# Nested if loop iteration in python

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python and at a beginner stage. I am trying to create a loop which iterates within an internal loop with an conditional statement.Here is what i want to accomplish:

1)Iterates through the locations list that were defined before

2) For each location, iterate through each player in the players dictionary with a second, internal for-loop.

Here is my code :

```
locations = ['reddit.com', 'amazon.com', 'twitter.com', 'linkedin.com', 'ebay.com', 'netflix.com', 'google.com', 'stackoverflow.com', 'github.com', 'quora.com']

players = {1: {'player_name': 'cynthia', 'time_played': 30.9, 'player_pokemon': {}, 'gyms_visited': []}, 2: {'player_name': 'teri', 'time_played': 22.2, 'player_pokemon': {}, 'gyms_visited': ['alcatraz', 'pacific_beach']}}


for loc in locations:
   for player in players.keys(): 
    if player["gyms_visited"] != loc[""]:
        print (loc, player)
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: `loc[""]`? `loc` is a string.

Comment: Is `if player["gyms_visited"] not in loc:` what you want?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ No, `loc` is a string.

Comment: Thanks for replying back , i m getting a Type error

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems here:

- `loc` is an *element* of the `locations` list, so a string, you cannot call `[""]` on a string; and
- `player` is an *element* from the *key* set of the dictionary. So it does *not* contain a `"gyms_visited"` list.

You should iterate over the `.values()` of the dictionary, and omit the `[""]` acces on the `loc`:

```
for loc in locations:
   for player in players.values():
    if player["gyms_visited"] != loc: # no [""]
        print (loc, player)
```

In case you want to print the player *key* instead of the dictionary, you can iterate over the `.items()` of the dictionary:

```
for loc in locations:
   for player_id,player in players.items():
    if player["gyms_visited"] != loc:
        print (loc, player_id)
```

Now the `gyms_visited` of a player is a list. And a list is never equal to a string. So that can never happen. If you look however whether the `loc` is *in* the list of `gyms_visited`, you can use:

```
for loc in locations:
   for player_id,player in players.items():
    if loc in player["gyms_visited"]:
        print (loc, player_id)
```

Comment: `player["gyms_visited"]` is a list, and `loc` a string, comparing them won't do much

Comment: @UlysseBN: Well I discussed that in the edited answer. The most straightforward check should be to use `in`.

Comment: still I'm not sure that's op's goal, since the question is unclear. (and there's no _gym visited_ that match any of the location..)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ IMHO, this answer is objectively better in terms of formatting and how it explains the concept.

Comment: @NieDzejkob Well, if that's what the masses decree.